# Geocoder not working with “Geocode from another field”

Tags: 7, location

I'm trying to make Geocoder work but encountered the following issue: I installed Geocoder 7.x-1.2, and I want to use it with content from another field, namely Location 7.x-3.0-rc2. I installed Leaflet to try to display my nodes. When I create new nodes, the Geofield is not filled in anymore(it remains empty whatever the address I try to use). I installed Address Field 7.x-1.0-beta4 instead of Location but the same issue persisting.

Are there common issues that would make the geocoding fail? If not, is there a procedure to try to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be solved by installing the other version of [geofield](https://drupal.org/project/geofield) module Geofield 7.x-2.0-beta1 (don't use the 7.x-2.x-dev version).